# Observations meaning - OpenAI Gym

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to know the specification of the observation of `CartPole-v0` in OpenAI Gym(https://gym.openai.com/).

For example, in the following code outputs `observation`. One observation is like `[-0.061586   -0.75893141  0.05793238  1.15547541]` I want to know what the numbers mean. And I want any way to know the specification of other `Environments` such as `MountainCar-v0`, `MsPacman-v0` and so on.

I tried to read https://github.com/openai/gym, but I don't know that. Would you tell me the way to know the specifications?

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(20):
    observation = env.reset()
    for t in range(100):
        env.render()
        print(observation)
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        if done:
            print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
            break
```

(from https://gym.openai.com/docs)

The output is the following

```
[-0.061586   -0.75893141  0.05793238  1.15547541]
[-0.07676463 -0.95475889  0.08104189  1.46574644]
[-0.0958598  -1.15077434  0.11035682  1.78260485]
[-0.11887529 -0.95705275  0.14600892  1.5261692 ]
[-0.13801635 -0.7639636   0.1765323   1.28239155]
[-0.15329562 -0.57147373  0.20218013  1.04977545]
Episode finished after 14 timesteps
[-0.02786724  0.00361763 -0.03938967 -0.01611184]
[-0.02779488 -0.19091794 -0.03971191  0.26388759]
[-0.03161324  0.00474768 -0.03443415 -0.04105167]
```

Comment: I believe this is the class https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py

Answer (score 9):

The observation space used in OpenAI Gym is not exactly the same with the original paper. Look at OpenAI's [wiki](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/CartPole-v0) to find the answer. The observation space is a 4-D space, and each dimension is as follows:

`Num Observation             Min         Max
0   Cart Position           -2.4        2.4
1   Cart Velocity           -Inf        Inf
2   Pole Angle              ~ -41.8°    ~ 41.8°
3   Pole Velocity At Tip    -Inf        Inf`

Answer (score 4):

After the paragraph describing each environment in OpenAI Gym website, you always have a reference that explains in detail the environment, for example, in the case of [`CartPole-v0`](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0#barto83) you can find all details in:

> [Barto83] AG Barto, RS Sutton and CW Anderson, "Neuronlike Adaptive Elements That Can Solve Difficult Learning Control Problem", IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man, and Cybernetics, 1983.

In that paper you can read that the cart-pole has four state variables:

1. position of the cart on the track
2. angle of the pole with the vertical
3. cart velocity
4. rate of change of the angle

So, the `observation` is simply a vector with the value of the four state variables.

Similarly, the details of the `MountainCar-v0` can be found in

> [Moore90] A Moore, Efficient Memory-Based Learning for Robot Control, PhD thesis, University of Cambridge, 1990.

and so on.